# gdb on Ubuntu 19.10 showing wrong variable values

Tags: gcc, gdb

Since upgrading to Ubuntu 19.10, gdb (8.3) is nearly unusable using programs compiled using the default gcc (9.2.1) using `-O0 -ggdb -g3` because most displayed values for variables are wrong.

The project used to use `-gdwarf-2 -g3`.  According to the gcc docs `-ggdb` provides the best support, but it doesn't make a difference.

Note that on a Fedora 30 machine running gdb Fedora 8.3-7.fc30 and gcc 9.2.1, everything is working fine.  Both machines are x86_64.

Am I really the only one?  Just to show what happens:

```
Thread 1 "swipl" hit Breakpoint 1, PL_error (
    pred=0x214 <error: Cannot access memory at address 0x214>, arity=32767, 
    msg=0x7ffff7df9468 <PL_unify_int64__LD+52> "\311\303\363\017\036\372UH\211\345H\203\354`H\211}\250H\211u\240dH\213\004%(", id=4160516576)
    at ../src/pl-error.c:94
94  { GET_LD
(gdb) bt
#0  PL_error (pred=0x214 <error: Cannot access memory at address 0x214>, 
    arity=32767, 
    msg=0x7ffff7df9468 <PL_unify_int64__LD+52> "\311\303\363\017\036\372UH\211\345H\203\354`H\211}\250H\211u\240dH\213\004%(", id=4160516576)
    at ../src/pl-error.c:94
```

If we look a the call site, we see

```
    return PL_error(NULL, 0, NULL, ERR_PERMISSION_PROC,
            ATOM_redefine, ATOM_imported_procedure, proc);
```

The first three arguments are all 0, but gdb gives claims they have some bogus value.

Comment: Compiled gdb from source using https://medium.com/@simonconnah/compiling-and-installing-gdb-8-3-on-ubuntu-19-04-eac597e4cfb8.   This gives the same result with exactly the same bogus variable values.

Comment: Switching back to gcc-7 fixes the issues.   This seems to be a gcc rather than a gdb issue.   Remains why gcc-9 + gdb-8.3 do work fine on Fedora?

Comment: Just updated to Ubuntu 20.04, providing gcc 9.3.   The problem persists.  Considering that Fedora gets this right, this seems an Ubuntu issue.  Where should I report this to get attention?